# How to override onload methods in ClojureScript?

Tags: clojurescript

I am trying to override `onload` function of `document` and `Image` in ClojureScript. I think that `set!` should be possible to do it, but i am not getting any success. Relevant code is as follows :

```
(defn load-image [img-path]
  (let [img (js/Image.)]
    (do (set! (.-src img) img-path)
        img)))

(defn add-img-canvas [img-path width height]
  (let [img (load-image img-path)]
    (set! (.-onload img) 
          (fn [] ;; This function is never called.
            (let [canvas (get-scaled-canvas img width height)]
              (do (pr-str canvas)
                  (swap! game-state :canvas canvas)))))))

(defn hello-world []
  (let [count (atom 1)]
    (fn []
      [:div 
       [:h1 (:text @game-state)]
       [:div (do (swap! count inc) (str "count is " @count))]
       [:canvas (:canvas @game-state)]])))

(reagent/render-component [hello-world]
                          (. js/document (getElementById "app")))

(set! (.-onload js/document) 
      (fn [] ;; This function is also never called.
        (add-img-canvas (:img-src game-state) 100 130)))

;;(. js/document onload)
```

Anonymous functions in `add-img-canvas` is not getting called. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be down to the difference between `document.onload` vs `window.onload`. The latter does work as expected.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload) for more details between the two.

Comment: ok.. thanks would try that.. Also can you suggest something about `(set! (.-onload img)` i.e. image load. It is also not firing.

Comment: Regarding img, you may want to do an onload before attaching the src. See http://fragged.org/preloading-images-using-javascript-the-right-way-and-without-frameworks_744.html

Comment: @AshishNegi did you find a solution?

Comment: @mrcharlie i donot remember exactly.. but `window.onload` will work and also above comment by ducky was also helpful. i guess i ended up doing: https://github.com/ashishnegi/phogame/blob/master/src/cljs/phogame/core.cljs#L194